# Footer Background overlapping content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation

I have a [web page](http://codingkids.businesscatalyst.com/)). It is coded in HTML / CSS / JavaScript / Foundation / Bootstrap and w3.css. It has four parts: the navigation bar and logo, the title, the pricing table, and the footer. As you can see, the footer's background is covering part of the pricing table's background at the moment. Do you know how to fix this so that the footer only starts after the pricing table?
Here is the code for the web page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <!-- BC_OBNW -->
    <head>
        <title>Home - Coding Kids</title>
        <link href="/StyleSheets/ModuleStyleSheets.css" type="text/css" rel="StyleSheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript">var jslang='EN';</script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/w3.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/foundation.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/marketing_nav.css">
        <link href="/CatalystStyles/report_abuse.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/foundation.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/modernizr.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <span style="font-family : Raleway;">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar-blue">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div align="center">
                        <p></p>
                        <p>
                            <img id="resize" width="70%" src="../logo.png" alt="Coding Kids">
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">About</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="/">Products<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Silver</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Silver+</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Gold</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Gold+</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signUp"><img src="images/register.png" width="20"> Sign Up</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#logIn"><img src="images/login.png" width="20"> Login</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div id="signUp" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Sign Up</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Sign Up Box Goes Here</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="logIn" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Login Box Goes Here</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="well">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="jumbotron" style="background: skyblue; font-famiy: Raleway;">
                        <h1>Learn Coding, The Easy Way...</h1>
                        <p>Coding Kids is a great way to learn programming, and it is fun and easy to use.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="row medium-3 columns">
                        <div>
                            <ul class="pricing-table" data-equalizer-watch>
                                <li class="title">Silver</li>
                                <li class="price"><b>FREE</b> Forever!</li>
                                <li class="description">For kids who want to make websites</li>
                                <li class="bullet-item">HTML Tutorial</li>
                                <li class="bullet-item">Interactive Activities</li>
                                <li class="bullet-item">Real Time HTML Editor</li>
                                <li class="bullet-item">Ask Codey Coding Coding Support Service</li>
                                <li class="cta-button"><a class="a button" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signUp">Sign Up</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row medium-3 columns">
                        <div>
                            <ul class="pricing-table" data-equalizer-watch>
                                <li class="title">Silver+</li>
                                <li class="price">£10 once</li>
                                <li class="description">For kids who want to learn programming</li>
                                <li class="bullet-item">Scratch Tutorial</li>
                                <li class="bullet-item">Python Tutorial</li>
                                <li class="bullet-item">Tasks and Projects to Complete</li>
                                <li class="bullet-item">Everything in <b><i>Silver</i></b></li>
                                <li class="cta-button"><a class="a button" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signUp">Sign Up</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row medium-3 columns">
                        <div>
                            <ul class="pricing-table" data-equalizer-watch>
                                <li class="title">Gold</li>
                                <li class="price">£99.99 a year</li>
                                <li class="description">For Primary Schools</li>
                                <li class="bullet-item">Easy Scratch Tutorial with Tasks and Projects to Complete</li>
                                <li class="bullet-item">Easy Word and PowerPoint Tutorials</li>
                                <li class="bullet-item">Easy Esafety Lesson and Quiz</li>
                                <li class="bullet-item">Online Worksheets</li>
                                <li class="cta-button"><a class="a button" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signUp">Sign Up</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row medium-3 columns">
                        <div style="background-image: url(images/goldplus.jpg)">
                            <ul class="pricing-table" data-equalizer-watch>
                                <li class="title">Gold+</li>
                                <li class="price">£299.99 a year</li>
                                <li class="description">For Secondary Schools</li>
                                <li class="bullet-item">MSWLogo Tutorial and Cheatsheet</li>
                                <li class="bullet-item">Kodu Tutorial with Tasks and Projetcs to Complete</li>
                                <li class="bullet-item">Esafety Lesson and Quiz</li>
                                <li class="bullet-item">Online Worksheets</li>
                                <li class="bullet-item">Everything in <b><i>Silver</i></b> and <b><i>Silver+</i></b></li>
                                <li class="cta-button"><a class="a button" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signUp">Sign Up</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <footer
            <div class="panel panel-default" style="background-color: black;">
                <div class="panel-body" style="background-color: black; color: white;">&copy; Coding Kids</div>
            </div>
            </footer>
        </span>
        <div id="report-abuse"><a href="http://www.businesscatalyst.com/report-abuse?URL=codingkids.businesscatalyst.com"><span>Report Abuse</span></a></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The footer is <div id="report-abuse"> ?

And there is some problems with your HTML code : if you choose XHTML close all your tags and don't use HTML5 tag like <nav>.
And don't use <font> tag, but CSS fonts.

Comment: fyi,font and center are deprecated html tags.

Comment: No, the footer is the bit that says (c) Coding Kids.

Comment: So first, use the html5 DTD, remove deprecated tags and use html5 tag like <footer>. It will be clearer for us and easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pricing section use floating elements, so you need to had to css property to the following element (your footer) :

```
clear: both;
```

Even better, add a div full width, 1px height, with the clear both css property in the same container as your floating elements.